# Make 1st "NOT_Ready" and every other "NOT_READY" state which comes after "LOGOUT" State state as "LOGIN

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT A.agent_id
    ,event_time
    ,A.STATE
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT a.agent_id
        ,event_time
        ,STATE
    FROM AGENT_MRD_STATE_EVENTS A
    WHERE event_time BETWEEN '2020-05-02 00:00:00'
            AND '2020-05-02 23:59:59'
        AND a.agent_id = 104
        AND STATE = 'NOT_READY'
    
    UNION ALL
    
    SELECT DISTINCT agent_id
        ,event_time
        ,STATE
    FROM AGENT_MRD_STATE_EVENTS A
    WHERE event_time BETWEEN '2020-05-02 00:00:00'
            AND '2020-05-02 23:59:59'
        AND agent_id = 104
        AND STATE = 'LOGOUT'
    ) A
ORDER BY A.event_time
```

Is there any way I can make 1st "`NOT_Ready`" and every other "`NOT_READY`" state which comes after "`LOGOUT`" State state as "`LOGIN`.

There are no "`LOGIN`" states in the table.

When the agent login the 1st `trigger` is fired of "`NOT_Ready`" which is considered to be a "`LOGIN`".

The 1st trigger of "`NOT_READY`" & every other "`NOT_READY`" `trigger` which comes after "`LOGOUT`" needs to be changed by hard-coding to "`LOGIN`"

[image: Result Set]

Comment: instead of posting an image you should consider posting data itself. That way it is reproducible

Comment: I tried to do that but its creating the image link.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2w6f.jpg

Comment: The link is of the pic having result set

Comment: that is because you have an image in your clipboard instead of text data

Comment: That not what Onyambu mean, instead post formatted text.

Comment: How did you do that ?

Comment: There are lots of ways here is an example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64886932/convert-multiple-rows-into-a-single-row-in-sql-server

Comment: Sample data *and* desired results would really help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with window functions that can look forwards and back on the rows within the defined window partition:

```
Select 
A.agent_id,
A.event_time,
A.state,
case when lag(A.state,1,'LOGOUT') over (partition by A.agent_id
                                        order by a.event_time
                                       ) = 'LOGOUT'
     then 'LOGIN'
     else A.state
     end as NewState

from
(SELECT DISTINCT
  a.agent_id,
  event_time,
  state
FROM AGENT_MRD_STATE_EVENTS A

WHERE event_time BETWEEN '2020-05-02 00:00:00' AND '2020-05-02 23:59:59'
AND a.agent_id = 104
AND state = 'NOT_READY'

Union All 

SELECT DISTINCT
  agent_id,
  event_time,
  state
FROM AGENT_MRD_STATE_EVENTS A
WHERE event_time between '2020-05-02 00:00:00' and '2020-05-02 23:59:59'
AND agent_id = 104
AND state = 'LOGOUT'
)A
Order by A.event_time
```